# want to update projectStatus according to priority wise

Tags: reactjs, node.js

I want to update projectStatus according to priority wise (overdue, due today, todo) but I got first status always. I have tried so many time but I am not get solution.

data in item as below formate

item {
id: '174ff95c-93de-471c-8098-0b5ca94580df',
projectId: '5215629b-64e0-44e1-846d-cf87da3a4a75',
name: 'Asbestos Testing/ACP-5',
groupName: 'Design & Building Approval',
startDate: 2023-12-06T00:00:00.000Z,
endDate: 2023-12-20T00:00:00.000Z,
portal: false,
status: { id: 'TODO', label: 'To Do' },
deleted: false,
assignedTo: [
{
id: '447abd28-e8ec-4326-b638-wwwfsa',
name: 'Devid Lee'
}
]
}

```
        var dueTodayMax = 0;
        var overdueMax = 0;
        var todoMax = 0;
        var projectStatus = null;

        const constructionItemsByAddress = constructionItems?.reduce((acc, item) => {
            const projectDetail = projectDetails.find(proj => proj.id === item.projectId);
            const formattedStartDate = moment(item.startDate).format('YYYY-MM-DD');
            const formattedEndDate = moment(item.endDate).format('YYYY-MM-DD');

            const today = new Date();
            const taskDueDate = new Date(formattedEndDate);

            let tempStartDate = moment(taskDueDate).format("DD-MM-YYYY");
            let tempEndDate = moment(today).format(
                "DD-MM-YYYY"
            );

            let overdueDays = businessMoment(tempEndDate, "DD-MM-YYYY").businessDiff(
                businessMoment(tempStartDate, "DD-MM-YYYY"),
                "days"
            );

            if (!acc[projectDetail.Address]) {

                if (item.status.id === 'OVERDUE' && overdueDays > overdueMax) {
                    overdueMax = overdueDays;
                    projectStatus = {
                        statusLabel: item.status.label,
                        statusId: item.status.id,
                        message: item.status.message || `+${overdueDays} Days`
                    };
                } else if (item.status.id === 'DUE' && overdueDays > dueTodayMax) {
                    dueTodayMax = overdueDays;
                    projectStatus = {
                        statusLabel: item.status.label,
                        statusId: item.status.id,
                        message: item.status.message || ""
                    };
                } else if (item.status.id === 'TODO' && overdueDays > todoMax) {
                    todoMax = overdueDays;
                    projectStatus = {
                        statusLabel: item.status.label,
                        statusId: item.status.id,
                        message: item.status.message || ""
                    };
                }
            }

            if (!acc[projectDetail.Address]) {
                acc[projectDetail.Address] = {
                    address: projectDetail.Address,
                    payment_milestone: { label: projectDetail.mile },
                    budget_balance: projectDetail.budget,
                    status: null,
                    itemsList: []
                };
                acc[projectDetail.Address].status = projectStatus;
            }

            let status = {
                statusLabel: item.status.label,
                statusId: item.status.id,
                message: item.status.message || `+${overdueDays} Days`
            }

            acc[projectDetail.Address].itemsList.push({
                itemId: item.id,
                dealId: projectDetail.dealId,
                clientDetail: projectDetail.clientDetail,
                name: item.name,
                from: formattedStartDate,
                to: formattedEndDate,
                clientPortal: item.portal,
                status: status
            });

            return acc;
        }, {});
```